# madlibs generator webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use only 1 input bar to cycle through different prompts asking the user to input nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc. I want it to cycle through every time the user presses the 'enter' key. And at the very end, I want the entire madlib paragraph to print out at the bottom with the stored user input values. I think using an array was correct in order to store the user input values.. I'm stuck. Am I doing this right??

full codepen with HTML and CSS here (to see my simple concept idea): https://codepen.io/stanimal93/pen/GRJGeEb

```
let prompt = document.getElementById('prompt');
let input = document.getElementById('userinput');
let madlib = document.getElementById('madlibparagraph');

input.addEventListener("keyup", submit(event));
input.addEventListener("keyup", resetInput);
input.addEventListener("keyup", changePrompt);

function submit(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();

  }
}


function resetInput() {
  input.value = "" // to clear the input
}


function changePrompt() {
  let word = new Array();

  word[0] = "a location: "
  word[1] = "a living thing: "
  word[2] = "a name: "
  word[3] = "a kind of food: "
  word[4] = "a noun: "
  word[5] = "a verb: "
  word[6] = "a color: "
  word[7] = "a plural noun: "
  word[8] = "a sound: "

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    prompt.innerHTML = word[i];
    word[i] = input.value
  };
}



// var location = "a location: "
// var livingThing = "a living thing: "
// var name = "a name: "
// var food = "a kind of food: "
// var noun = "a noun: "
// var verb = "a verb: "
// var color = "a color: "
// var pluralNoun = "a plural noun: "
// var sound = "a sound: "

// let words = [location, livingThing, name, food, noun, verb, color, pluralNoun, sound]




let madib.innerHTML = "Once upon a time in " + _______ + ", there was a " + _______ + " named " + _________ + ". The world was stricken by coronavirus in the year 2020 and there was no " + ________ + " to eat anymore. " + ________ + " went outside to find " + _________ + " and realized everyone was " + ________ + ". There were " + ________ + " colored " + __________ + " and you could hear " + ___________ + " in the distance.";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and finished it myself and it is bug free! I had trouble wrapping my head around using a for loop as opposed to an if statement during an eventListener keypress event, along with a fadein type of function. Feel free to play it! in this codepen: https://codepen.io/stanimal93/pen/GRJGeEb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
let prompt = document.getElementById('prompt');
let input = document.getElementById('userinput');
let madlib = document.getElementById('madlibparagraph');

function resetInput() {
  input.value = '' // to clear the input
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      prompt.style.opacity = 0;
      storeAnswer();
      resetInput();
      setTimeout(fadein, 500);
      function fadein() {
          prompt.style.opacity = 1;
          changePrompt();
      }
  }
});

let word = new Array();
    word[0] = "a living thing: "
    word[1] = "a name: "
    word[2] = "a kind of food: "
    word[3] = "a noun: "
    word[4] = "a verb: "
    word[5] = "a color: "
    word[6] = "a plural noun: "
    word[7] = "a sound: "
    word[8] = "Read your madlib below!"


var i = 0
function changePrompt() {
    if (i < 9) {
      console.log(i);
      prompt.innerHTML = word[i];
      console.log(answer);
      i++
    }
    if (i === 9) {
      madlib.innerHTML = "Once upon a time in " + answer[0].toUpperCase().bold() + ", there was a " + answer[1].toUpperCase().bold() + " named " + answer[2].toUpperCase().bold() + ". The world was stricken by coronavirus in the year 2020 and there was no " + answer[3].toUpperCase().bold() + " to eat anymore. " + answer[2].toUpperCase().bold() + " went outside to find " + answer[4].toUpperCase().bold() + " and realized everyone was " + answer[5].toUpperCase().bold() + ". There were " + answer[6].toUpperCase() + " colored " + answer[7].toUpperCase().bold() + " and you could hear " + answer[8].toUpperCase().bold() + " in the distance.";
    }
}

function storeAnswer() {
  for (var a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
    answer[i] = input.value;
  }
}


let answer = new Array();
    answer[0] = ""
    answer[1] = ""
    answer[2] = ""
    answer[3] = ""
    answer[4] = ""
    answer[5] = ""
    answer[6] = ""
    answer[7] = ""
    answer[8] = ""
```

});